# Traefik default certificate not working inside docker-compose.yml but works in external dynamic configuration

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, traefik

I am trying to set up Traefik with Docker Compose, and I have come across an issue with the default certificate configuration. I have successfully set up the default certificate using an external dynamic configuration file, but when I try to move the same configuration inside the docker-compose.yml file, it does not seem to work.

Here are the lines that work in the external dynamic configuration:

```
tls:
  stores:
    default:
      defaultCertificate:
        certFile: /etc/traefik/certs/cert.pem
        keyFile: /etc/traefik/certs/key.pem
```

However, when I move it into my docker-compose.yml file, it stops working. My question is, how can I make this configuration work inside the docker-compose.yml file? Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Here's the relevant part of my docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:
  traefik:
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --entrypoints.https.address=:443
      - --providers.docker
    image: traefik
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls=true"
      - "traefik.tls.stores.default.defaultcertificate.certfile=/etc/traefik/certs/cert.pem"
      - "traefik.tls.stores.default.defaultcertificate.keyfile=/etc/traefik/certs/key.pem"
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./traefik/cert.pem:/etc/traefik/certs/cert.pem
      - ./traefik/key.pem:/etc/traefik/certs/key.pem
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: I read that it isn't possible to do it with labels. The solution I found was to reference a config file and define the default certificates there.

Comment: The config file works, however, it ignores the certfile/keyfile config, or even shows the config file as invalid if I only configure the tls-stores. I haven't found out why yet.